# Odoo 15: Complex view inheritance

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-15

I would like to create a new "E-Commerce" tab in the product form and move the fields added
by the website module into it.

Creating the new tab :

```
<record id="product_ecom_tab" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Product Ecom Tab Form</field>
  <field name="model">product.template</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//page[@name='sales']" position="after">
      <page name="product_ecom" string="E-Commerce">
      </page>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

So then I though I could simply change the view used by the website :

```
<record id="product_ecom_details_move" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Product Ecom Details Move</field>
  <field name="model">product.template</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="website_sale.product_template_form_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//xpath[2]" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="expr">//page[@name='product_ecom']</attribute>
      <attribute name="position">inside</attribute>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Two problem here :

1. Cannot select xpath tag and modify its expr attribute
2. In this view, I cannot refer to page added in another inherited view

Any clean solution ?

Comment: Could you please check the depends of your manifest file? Maybe you are missing a depends to website_sale?

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do from your question, but I think the details below should help regardless. Both of these issues seem to come from confusion about how we might expect view inheritance to work vs how Odoo designed it to work.

> 1. Cannot select xpath tag and modify its expr attribute

*See [Odoo Views documentation about Inheritance Specs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#inheritance-specs) for reference.*

When you are inheriting with `xpath`, you will never use `xpath` in the actual `expr` of your `xpath` node.

```xml
<!-- This doesn't work -->
<xpath expr="//xpath[2]" position="attributes">
```

The above doesn't work, because Odoo is going to try to apply your view inheritance on top of a "rendered" view, which will already have resolved that view's `xpath`.

Instead, you need to write your `xpath` to a portion of the "rendered" view.

**View you want to inherit**

```xml
<!-- The xpath or any other node with a `position` will not be rendered in the final view -->
<xpath expr="//page[@name='sales']" position="after">
    <!-- The contents of the xpath or any other `position` node **will* be rendered -->
    <page name="product_ecom" string="E-Commerce">
    </page>
</xpath>
```

**Your view, which inherits from the above view**

```xml
<!-- Hook your `expr` onto a rendered element -->
<xpath expr="//page[@name='product_ecom']" position="inside">
    <!-- For inside/before/after, your content will be rendered -->
    <page name="my_new_page" string="My New Page">
    </page>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//page[@name='product_ecom']" position="attributes">
    <!-- For attributes, your content will change an existing rendered element -->
    <attribute name="string">New page label</attribute>
</xpath>
```

---

> 2. In this view, I cannot refer to page added in another inherited view

It depends on the view inheritance of whatever you're trying to refer to. For example, consider the following structure:

```
product.product_template_form_view
├── other_module.website_sale.product_template_form_view
│   └── yet_another_module.product_template_form_view
└── website_sale.product_template_form_view
```

If I am inheriting `product.product_template_form_view`, but I want to refer to an element from `yet_another_module.product_template_form_view`, then Odoo may do a couple of "not great" things, such as:

- It can render my view before the `yet_another_module` view, which would result in an error.
- If the `yet_another_module` app is uninstalled and my app doesn't depend on it, then we result in another potential error.

If I want to refer to something from the `yet_another_module` app, then I need to (1) depend on that module in my module's `__manifest__.py` and (2) write a view that specifically inherits from the `yet_another_module` view.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took.

I want to create a new tab in the product template (product.product_template_form_view) and move the block created by the website_sale module to this new tab without breaking any module based on it (like website_sale_stock and product_template_form_view_inherit_website_sale_stock)

Comment: @Steff You should be able to do that without too much trouble, I think. Basically, you will first want to do `<xpath expr="..." position="replace"/>` against the block you want to move. Then, do `<xpath expr="..." position="after">` against the page you want to have before your new page. When you add your new page, just re-add the "replaced" XML and the other views should still be able to find the element in the new location. Just make sure your view inherits before those other views (adjust your view's "priority"/"sequence")